# google spreadsheet feeds with multiple worksheets

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-feed-api

How to get feeds from multiple sheets using `google spreadsheet feeds` api?
Below URL fetches the feeds from first sheet only. In my `spreadsheet` I have `3 work sheets` and I want to fetch remaining sheets data as well.

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/XXXXMYKEYXXXX/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script
```

How to fetch them?

I tried below without success:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/XXXXMYKEYXXXX/od7/public/values?alt=json-in-script
```

Note `od7` instead of `od6`

**UPDATE**
URL for the spreadsheet feed is 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1c53H0piyduOV6zRwS54A7MDZ3SooJOmj4O52Xd0dyIA/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script

In the spreadsheet I have `TopicA`,`TopicB`,`TopicC` sheets. Feeds response contains `TopicA` information only.

Comment: See my comments to my answer. Your other worksheetids are in that url's response.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems worksheet IDs are numbered from 1 to n and not like od6, od7.
Using below urls, I was able to get individual worksheet's data 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1c53H0piyduOV6zRwS54A7MDZ3SooJOmj4O52Xd0dyIA/1/public/values?alt=json  fetches first worksheet 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1c53H0piyduOV6zRwS54A7MDZ3SooJOmj4O52Xd0dyIA/2/public/values?alt=json   2nd sheet 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1c53H0piyduOV6zRwS54A7MDZ3SooJOmj4O52Xd0dyIA/3/public/values?alt=json  3rd sheet and so on

Note the `/1`, `/2` and `/3` after the key (1c53H0piyduOV6zRwS54A7MDZ3SooJOmj4O52Xd0dyIA) in the url

Comment: thanks for the great answer, have you come across a way to know how many sheets are in a spreadsheet?  Eg at the moment my user has 2 but I want them to be able to keep adding to it, so I want to run a loop saying for each sheet give me the data.  Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: @ak85 I did not proceed with worksheet approach for my requirement. I wanted some `json` content and worksheets approach resulted in lot of bytes exchange over network for small amounts of json data. Instead I wrote a simple python application to return me the required json. Sorry this does not answer your question in the comment. I didn't explore much as the worksheet solution didn't meet my requirement

Answer (score 3):

Per [the Google Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_information_about_worksheets):

> To determine the URL of a given spreadsheet's worksheets feed, find
>   that spreadsheet's entry in the spreadsheets feed, as described in the
>   previous section. Then examine the link element that has
>   rel="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#tablesfeed". That
>   element's href value provides the URL for that spreadsheet's
>   worksheets feed.
>
> To request a list of worksheets in a given spreadsheet, issue a GET
>   request to that URL, with an appropriate authorization header:
>
> GET https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/key/private/full

The returned result contains a URL for each worksheet in that spreadsheet, which you can then query to pull information from each worksheet you want to get data from. So in your example, *od6* is a valid worksheetId, but you must discern the other worksheetIds from the spreadsheet's feed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do not see the other worksheets information in the feeds. I updated the question with actual URL which you can hit to verify the feed response.

Comment: That URL is not the spreadsheet feed, that is the list feed for a specific worksheet, TopicA.

Comment: Here is the URL for the spreadsheet feed https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1c53H0piyduOV6zRwS54A7MDZ3SooJOmj4O52Xd0dyIA/public/full

Comment: I am sorry. I did not understand `Your other worksheetids are in that url's response`. URL you mentioned lists the worksheet names. I need the data in those worksheets like the list api response. the Url I mentioned gives me the data from worksheet-1.

Comment: In the URL I sent you are some *id* elements. Each of those corresponds to a worksheet feed URL which you can use to get the list feed URLs.

Comment: How would you return your suggestion as json?  Answer:  just append ?alt=json

Answer (score 1):

Building on suman j's answer, here's a way to load multiple sheets, regardless of how many there are, using jQuery.

Load the spreadsheet's main JSON feed, find the url for each sheet in the JSON that's returned, tweak the url a bit, then load that one as well. Then use `ajaxStop` to take any action that needs to happen after they all finish loading.

```
$(function(){
    var feedurl_start = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/";
    var feedkey = "1c53H0piyduOV6zRwS54A7MDZ3SooJOmj4O52Xd0dyIA";

    $.getJSON(feedurl_start+"worksheets/"+feedkey+"/public/basic?alt=json", function(sheetfeed) {
        $.each(sheetfeed.feed.entry, function(k_sheet, v_sheet){
            var sheeturl = v_sheet.link[0]["href"]+"?alt=json";
            sheeturl = sheeturl.replace("basic", "values");
            var sheet_title = v_sheet.content["$t"]; // to know which sheet you're dealing with
            console.log(sheet_title);
            $.getJSON(sheeturl, function(sheetjson){
                console.log(sheetjson);
            });
        });
    });
});

// Since you're making multiple AJAX calls, use ajaxStop
// to do whatever you need to do AFTER everything is loaded
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    // now all your data is loaded, so you can use it here.
});
```